# How do I get the underlying bean configuration equivalent for any XML namespace in Spring?

Tags: xml, spring, xsd, xml-namespaces

Does this follow a common namespace design pattern for XML in such a way that I can deduce exactly what beans belong to what namespace? If not, how can I inspect the underlying API in order to make an accurate assessment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out, but you have to dig through some code. The entry-point for processing a namespace is an implementation of `org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandler`. This implementation will typically set up a number of `org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParser` implementations to handle the various top-level elements in that namespace.

The `NamespaceHandler` implementations are usually named according to the schema they support, but that is not guaranteed. To determine without doubt which handler is reponsible for a given namespace, you need to find the `spring.handlers` file that defines that namespace handler. That file will be located in the META-INF folder of the containing jar.

For example:
In the META-INF folder in spring-tx-[version].jar there is a `spring.handlers` file with the following line:

```
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tx=org.springframework.transaction.config.TxNamespaceHandler
```

That is, the `tx` namespace is handled by the `TxNamespaceHandler`. If you look in the source-code of that handler, in the `init()` you will see

```
registerBeanDefinitionParser("advice", new TxAdviceBeanDefinitionParser());
```

which means that a `<tx:advice>` statement in your spring xml is processed by the `org.springframework.transaction.config.TxAdviceBeanDefinitionParser`. You can drill down into any `spring.handlers` and `NamespaceHandler` in a similar way.